# Matplotlib - Mpld3 fig_to_html() in Django

Tags: django, matplotlib, mpld3

I am trying to dispaly a scatter of points in mpld3 in my browser.

This is my views.py snippet:

```
plt.scatter([1, 10], [5, 9])
fig = plt.figure()
html_graph = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)

return render(request, 'home.html', {'graph': [html_graph]})
```

And inside of home.html:

```
{% for elem in graph %}
   {{elem|safe}}
{% endfor %}
```

But the only thing I see are the controls. I also tried it with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplot()
```

But this only displays the controls along with the graph, without the scattered points.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first create the figure, then plot the scatter to it.

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter([1, 10], [5, 9])
html_graph = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
```

or, maybe better

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1, 10], [5, 9])
html_graph = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
```

because in the latter case you are sure to plot the scatter to the axes `ax` that is part of the figure you are showing.

Comment: I get a 'main thread not in main loop' exception every once in a while, do you know what that is or if it's related to this approach?

Comment: No, I have no idea where that comes from. It should not depend on this code here, and "once in a while" really does not sound like a problem with the code itself.

Comment: I am trying to import matplotlib to run this code in my app like this `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3` but it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpld3'`, How do I solve this ? I already have matplotlib installed

Comment: @Rahul If you want to use `mpld3` you need to install it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did that and it works like a charm but could you help me with one other thing ?